# Using grep in log file

Tags: python, subprocess

How do i place grep in the below string. I seem to be not getting it right.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-10", "/datax/qantas/run/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-02-29.txt" "|" "grep /checkout-qantas/int/price?"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

gives me

```
tail: cannot open /datax/qantas/run/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-02-29.txt|grep /checkout-qantas/int/price?' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used shell keyword pipe (`|`), so you need to set `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen("tail -10 ... | grep ....", shell=True)
```

If you want to save the output:

```
out = subprocess.check_output("tail -10 ... | grep ....", shell=True)
```

---

Better not to use `shell=True`, use `subprocess.PIPE` instead e.g.:

```
>>> out = subprocess.Popen(['tail',  '-10',  '/var/log/syslog'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> subprocess.check_call(['grep', 'UDP'], stdin=out.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

`shell = True` and putting your complete command in quote should help you-

```
p = subprocess.Popen('tail -10 /datax/qantas/run/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2016-02-29.txt  | grep /checkout-qantas/int/price?', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

Comment: I doubt it will work on linux shell, What exactly this GET does?, never seen such shell command

Comment: Hi Alok, its working for me, it was not working in the linux shell but when i made it work there then its executing in my python script. Thanks.